# Azure S2S VPN Routing to Another Region VNET

Tags: azure, azure-networking

Learning at a million miles an hour here, testing Route vs Policy VPNs in MSDN in prep for a big push live.

I have VNET1 in AustraliaEast and VNET2 in SouthEastAsia, successfully created the VPN between them and confirm using hosts in either.

I have also similated an OnPrem-To-Azure S2S VPN using StrongSwan. I believe I have configured it to know about both VNETs IP ranges;

```
rightsubnet=10.61.200.0/22,10.65.200.0/22

...

Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
   azure[1]: ESTABLISHED 35 minutes ago, 192.168.1.1[LocalIP]...X.X.X.X[AzureIP]
   azure{1}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, ESP in UDP SPIs: c62f3c80_i 2ba5c8c0_o
   azure{1}:   0.0.0.0/0 === 10.61.200.0/22 10.65.200.0/22
```

I can successfully ping the VNET1 range, which is has the Virtual Network Gateway I have connected to. I was hoping (assuming?) that I would also be able to ping the VNET2 as well - but I cant :O(

It is possible to get the three networks to see each other this way or do you have to create a S2S VPN to each Regional VNET?

I looked at Azure Routing Tables but did have any luck.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: as an update adding a second vpn tunnel to VNET2 works;

Comment: but i'd like to know if I can get way without needing it

Comment: It is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is possible to get the three networks to see each other this way or
>   do you have to create a S2S VPN to each Regional VNET?

No, it is not possible. For a S2S VPN, there is no derived transitive relationship. So, if you want to connect your local to VNet 2, you need create a new VPN tunnel. Other words, in your scenario, you need create 3 VPN tunnels.

Note: You should select Route policy VPN gateway, Policy VPNs don't support multiple VPN tunnels.